# Is using DOM tags in xpath locators a good practice?

Tags: java, selenium, dom, xpath

In my test cases, more than often I'm using XPath locators that check text attributes. For example,

```
public By label(String text) {
    return By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'"+text+"')]");
}
```

and in test cases I use it like:

```
webUI.verifyElementVisible(page.label("message"));
```

I am doing this with labels, divs, inputs (placeholder), spans, etc.

Is this considered good practice?

What would be the downsides of doing this in the future?

This greatly shortens my development time, makes my page object repositories much cleaner and concise.

Comment: This question will have very opinion based answer. One thing that is not good practice is to use text nodes selection in mixed content (text and markup) whether XPath or any language. It's better to use the string value precisely because of inline markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Key Point :** CSS selector is highly recommended over XPath due to its simplicity, speed, and performance.

**Remember :** Xpath engines are different in each browser, hence make them inconsistent.

**Specially,** IE does not have a native xpath engine, therefore selenium injects its own xpath engine for compatibility of its API. Hence we lose the advantage of using native browser features that WebDriver inherently promotes.

**Hence,** larger audience would recommend to use CSS over Xpath.

**Example :** CSS Selector for a label (text): label[for=city]

```
<label for="city">New York</label>
```

Comment: I didn't think you could find elements using CSS that contained certain text. Can you add an example to your answer?

Comment: please check updated answer for a text which is wrapped with a label tag.

Comment: That CSS selector does not target the label tag by its text.

Comment: This is misleading... XPath/XSLT 1.0 is cross browser compatible (with one or two corner case exception *regarding Firefox*). As comments above, complex selection about text content is not posible in CSS. But it's correct about the dependy between IE and MSXML (great MS library for XML services). [See details of this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-dom1x/a1383b4d-7408-437e-a22b-71a7dab51f66). Something that is missing is that Selenium has its own [XPath engine to provide for IE6-8](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html#does-selenium-2-support-xpath-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

That's one of my reasons for using Xpath (the other reason is backward DOM tree traversal). I would usually use CSS selectors when possible, but when looking for a specific text on a page, Xpath-element[contains(.,"text")] is my preferred choice.

I think that is a very elegant way of checking the dynamically created table elements, for example.